# how to display serializer in delete action with django rest swagger

Tags: django, swagger, swagger-ui, django-rest-swagger

By default, [django rest swagger](https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) doesn't displayed the Serializer in `DELETE` method. But, for some reason I need to implement prevent deletion & force deletion case.

So, basicly to implement it, we need to add e.g this example inside the request body:

```
{
  "forceDelete": true
}
```

I'm trying to update the serializer inside `get_serializer_class` function, but it still doesn't work properly.

```
class ForceDeleteSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    force_delete = serializers.BooleanField(default=False)


class GroupViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsOrganizationAdmin,)
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    search_fields = ('display_name',)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'destroy':
            return ForceDeleteSerializer
        return self.serializer_class
```

[image: delete action]

Comment: the package you are using is deprecated and not supporting custom schema. I recommend switching to `drf-yasg` (recommend by the author of  django rest swagger) because it has [customizable schema](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html)

Comment: @LinhNguyen hmm make sense. [oot: is there any refference to add GET parameters in Swagger]?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, as suggested by @LinhNguyen to use `drf-yasg`, and using `swagger_auto_schema` it worked.

```
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema

@swagger_auto_schema(request_body=ForceDeleteSerializer)
def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ....
```

[image: preview]